Entire disk encryption doesn't seem to work in plain mode, but it does work ok with LUKS. Why?
I am working on a minimal linux distro that needs to be installed on embedded device. The way installation process works right now is that the installer is a Linux itself, with initramfs based on busybox with few additional tools (e.g. cryptsetup). The disk layout is very simple -- single partition. No need for LVM. Currently the installer wipes the disk clean, creates that single partition, and populate this partition from an image using 'dd'. I know I should fill the disk with random data, but for the purpose of this example let's ignore that. What I am trying to do is:
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1M count=200
cryptsetup --cipher=<some cipher:some hash> --offset=0 open --type plain /dev/sdb encvolume
mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/encvolume
mount /dev/mapper/encvolume /mnt
echo "SECRET INFO" > /mnt/SECRET
umount /mnt
cryptsetup close encvolume

Of course, I am being asked for password. Interestingly when I try to unlock the drive again, using exactly same cryptsetup open command, it doesn't work: fdisk reports that there is no valid partition on /dev/sdb, as though encryption failed.
On the other hand, similar commands, but with Luks seem to be working ok:
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1M count=200
cryptsetup --cipher=<some cipher:some hash> luksFormat /dev/sdb
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb encvolume
mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/encvolume
mount /dev/mapper/encvolume /mnt
echo "SECRET INFO" > /mnt/SECRET
umount /mnt
cryptsetup luksClose encvolume


cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb encvolume
mount /dev/mapper/encvolume /mnt

My guess is that I am missing some metadata that is derived indirectly from my original 'cryptsetup open' command, and that is missing on decryption ? I would prefer to use plain mode if possible. I would appreciate suggestions.

fdisk reports that there is no valid partition on /dev/sdb, as though encryption failed.: well, there isn't. You wiped the partition table. There's no partitions for fdisk to discover.

OK, but mount /dev/sdb doesn't work either. And LUKS version does..
